# How to count words in String

Tags: java, string, counter

I want to count the words in my String in a int variable.
For example:

```
String text = "Hello my friends";
int number = 3;
```

or

```
String text = "I think it is better to go";
int number = 7;
```

How can I do that?

Comment: you can see this link http://javahungry.blogspot.com/2013/06/count-number-of-words-in-string-example-java-program-code.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String text = "I think it is better to go";
int number = text.split(" ").length;
```

Comment: This is only correct, if all words are splittet with only one space. For example, if the sentence look like `Hello_my__friends` (underscores are spaces), this will output `4`instead of `3`! Just to mention...

Comment: Thank you @bobbel but that doesn't matter for me :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try following method.

```
int countWords (String input) {
   String trim = in.trim();
   if (trim.isEmpty()) return 0;
       //separate string around spaces
       return trim.split("\\s+").length; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `text.split(" ");` which will return you an `Array` of `String`s. You can find the number of words by getting the size of that array.

Answer (score 0):

Try to split the string with space string("\\s+") and count the size of array.

Comment: won't even compile.  '\\s+' is not a valid character literal.

Comment: Thanks changed my statement... :)